# Route Transition without the `data` requirement?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

See the [Angular Route Animations Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations)

The documentation above, and every other V4 tutorial out there, uses static data such as this to act as a trigger of some kind.

```
{ 
    path: 'about', 
    component: AboutComponent,
    data: {
        animation: 'AboutPage'
    } 
}
```

Which is used to decide the trigger or state?

```
prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
  return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
}
```

However, my router configuration is more like this:

```
{ 
    path: ':id', 
    component: CoolComponent,
}
```

So I have established that the function being used as a trigger doesn't really make sense. I need to replace that with something more generic.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: Why not to subscribe to router events and handle global trigger

Comment: Thanks Pardeep! I am not sure how to but I will certainly take a dive down that rabbit hole.

Comment: For your convenience I have posted some code as an answer, have a look there let me know In case of any query,

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments you probably need to subscribe to router events globally somewhere may be in some service like this -

```
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
  if (this.router.url.includes('someURL')) {
    // trigger call
  } else {
    // some other code
  }
}
```

and you can listen to this global variable. Hope it helps you out.